# Storing a text file in iCloud in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, icloud

I need some clarification and Microsoft documentation is only confusing me more.
I want to save a txt file in iCloud so the user doesn't loose some data that belongs to them.
This db document is some information I am retrieving from a local database and storing in a text file. I have seen two ways of doing this.. however all the posts on this topic are very outdated and I don't know which way might be best or if they are even doing what I trying to do.

All I would like is to be able to have the user backup this particular file to their iCloud account, so they can still keep this info even if they change phones or delete the app and want to restore from iCloud.

Microsoft's documentation points me to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/introduction-to-icloud

I began setting up the provisioning profiles and setting the iCloud options on the entitlements page etc. However the documentation when sideways for me when they began creating a monkey page UI Document and having the user manager the ubiquity documents (which I don't want) I actually don't want the user even seeing this Txt file. However this option shows how to check if the iCloud is even turned on on this user's phone.

Now this other option I think is more straight forward and I read the documentation on it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system using something like this to store and retrieve a document:
`var libraryPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..", "Library");`
However what if iCloud is turned off? Is this an automatic backup option?

Any type of explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The iCloud storage API in iOS 5 allows applications to save user documents and application-specific data to a central location and access those items from all the user's devices.

About the definition of **[iCloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/introduction-to-icloud)**, you will know that it will save your data to cloud server. And it can be used in all the user's device if turn on the iCloud.

> However what if iCloud is turned off?Is this an automatic backup option?

Therefore, if iCloud is turned off, you could backup the data in device although it will not be used for other user's devices. You could save it in [Application directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories).  This should be a good chooice to backup your data. And you also can get the data when you need them.

In addition, you also can use other cloud server APIs to backup your data. Such as [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-storage), [Firebase Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Storage/) etc.

Comment: ah I see. This makes sense. I will eventually set my app up with firebase. But for the time being I just wanted to look into these two options. For the iCloud implementation do you know of any real life examples people have discussed. I have come across a handful of posts but all are very outdated and the documentation is very confusing.

Comment: @ppc Whether you have checked [the official sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/introductiontoicloud/)?